# Java MySql connection

Tags: java, mysql, cpanel

Java project not getting linked to mysql database when both are uploaded on third party server on c-panel. We are getting null pointer exception error msg (searchdaoimp.java:30) which is corresponding to the connection string. Our connection settings are as follows:

```
Host= 'ip address of the server' 
Database =database name 
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database name  
User=database username  
Password=database password
MySql connectionPort ='3306'
```

Project working offline on local computer via following settings:

```
Driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/muhealdb
User=****
Password=****
```

Comment: Please post the exception reported

Comment: Add more information. Question is not clear. Try to add the complete error , code sample etc

Comment: Well, i assume third party server use another url than localhost...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database name` 
Isn't it will be `url="jdbc:mysql://"+Host+":"+connectionPort+"/"+database name` ?